# Simple version of blockchain? Blockchain for training

Tags: blockchain

Please tell me whether there is a simple/lighter version of blockchain, you can install and learn "at home"?
Link?
Which implementation blockchain better learning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any software available for testing of Bitcoin security?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3024/is-there-any-software-available-for-testing-of-bitcoin-security)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a good resource to learn how \[technically\] bitcoin works?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/whats-a-good-resource-to-learn-how-technically-bitcoin-works)

Comment: Not marking as a duplicate because neither of those links mention the 'regtest' mode. user33730, google 'bitcoin regtest', it's a blockchain that doesn't connect with other computers and does require a lot of space on your computer to use.