# Blockchain research

Tags: blockchain

I am doing research on block chain malleability and I want to build my own blockchain prototype / testbed in order to practically see the malleability issues in blockchaining mechanism (like bitcoin). Is there any ideal tool available (esp in Python) which can best serve the purpose.

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any software available for testing of Bitcoin security?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3024/is-there-any-software-available-for-testing-of-bitcoin-security)

Comment: @cdecker Looks about right, but both answers are four years old. I've posted a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to have private blockchain to investigate malleability issues. You should start with learning ECDSA algorithms and data structures.

Trust me.

Comment: Also, OP can just do it on the Bitcoin testnet (or live, just don't make transactions where you give 15BTC to the miners).